# SQL Equivalent to pandas.merge_asof

Tags: python, sql, pandas, join, merge

Is there an SQL equivalent of **[pandas.merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)** where I can join two tables **on** a datetime and **by** a given field as well as specify a **direction** and a **tolerance**?

I'm trying to replicate something similar to the following:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='time', left_by='index_A', right_by='index_B', tolerance=pd.Timedelta('15 minutes'), direction='nearest')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved that with PySpark but you can use the same trick in SQL. You can see the code below to imitate the Pandas merge_asof.

```sql
-- Compute the absolute difference between two timestamp
CREATE TEMPORARY MACRO ABS_DIFF(t1 TIMESTAMP, t2 TIMESTAMP)
ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2));

-- Create two examples of table
WITH df1 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS index_A, CAST('2018-01-01 00:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP) AS `time`
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS index_A, CAST('2018-01-05 00:00:00' AS TIMESTAMP) AS `time`
), 
df2 AS (
    SELECT 1 AS index_B, CAST('2018-01-01 00:11:00' AS TIMESTAMP) AS `time`
    UNION
    SELECT 1 AS index_B, CAST('2018-01-01 00:14:00' AS TIMESTAMP) AS `time`
    UNION
    SELECT 2 AS index_B, CAST('2018-01-05 00:20:00' AS TIMESTAMP) AS `time`
)
SELECT `index`, time1, time2
FROM
    (SELECT 
        df1.index_A AS `index`, df1.`time` AS time1, df2.`time` AS time2,
        -- Order the duplicates on index by time ascending
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY df1.index_A ORDER BY ABS_DIFF(df1.`time`, df2.`time`) ASC) AS nth_row
    FROM df1, df2
    WHERE 
        -- Equal join on index
        df1.index_A = df2.index_B
        -- Join on absolute difference lowest than 15 minutes
        AND ABS_DIFF(df1.`time`, df2.`time`) / 60 <= 15) AS df3
-- Select the rows with the nearest times
WHERE nth_row = 1
```

So, as you can see you must follow these steps:

1. Join the tables on index and time if the absolute difference is lowest than 15 minutes.
2. Apply the window function ROW_NUMBER to eliminate the duplicated rows.

To do that you need to use a subquery because you aren't allow to use a window function in the WHERE clause.

I have only tested this code on **Hive 3.1.3000.7.1.7.88-2**.

Comment: Did you also measure the performance of this query? Because the nice thing about the pandas merge_asof is the high performance (it is blazing fast). This is because the way it uses the fact both dataframes are sorted. Maybe the query optimizer does some nice stuff with this query, but I am not sure it is completely certain of what the final goal is. So I am wondering, if you checked out the performance.